# Как сделать префиксную перегрузку бинарного оператора?

Tags: c++

Всем привет! Имеется такое задание:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сделать два пункта: a и b. Пункт a я сделал, а вот пункт b не знаю как сделать. Не пойму как это сделать.

Вот что я сделал:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
  int f;
  
  public:
  Test(int f)
  {
      this->f = f;
  }
  
  Test & operator + (int g)
  {
      this->f += g;
      
      return *this;
  }
  
  void print()
  {
      cout << this->f << endl;
  }
  
};

int main()
{
    Test a(5);
    a.print();
    a + 5;
    a.print();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если бы вам не было нужно приватное поле, тогда можно было бы снаружи класса просто написать вот так:

```
Test &operator+(int g, Test &test)
{
    test.f += g;      
    return test;
}
```

А чтобы иметь доступ к приватному полю, нужно:

- Либо в класс добавить `friend Test &operator+(int g, Test &test);`
- Либо, чтобы меньше писать, убрать оператор снаружи класса и вписать его тело внутрь класса, в конец строчки с `friend` (вместо `;`):

  ```
  friend Test &operator+(int g, Test &test) {...}
  ```

---

Еще, обратите внимание, что задание предлагает выбрать не арифметический оператор, так что `+`,`-`,`*`,`/` не подходят.

Comment: `Снаружи класса сделайте` типа сделать как дружественную функцию?

Comment: @Евгений Не заметил приватное поле, поправил.

Answer (score 0):

Как метод второй вариант не реализовать. Можно как функцию:

```
Test & operator +(int g, Test & test) {
    ...
    return test;
}
```

Если нужен доступ к приватным полям класса `Test`, функцию надо объявить как дружественную в теле класс Test:

```
friend Test & operator +(int g, Test & test);
```

Но и моей функции и у вашего метода плохой дизайн. Ещё раз, **плохой дизайн**: оператор `+` не должен менять свои аргументы. Гораздо лучше вернуть новую копию объекта. Это ожидаемое поведение оператора:

```
Test operator +(int g) const
{
    return Test(this->f + g);
}
```

Аналогично нужно изменить и функцию.

Обратите внимание что задание запрещает использовать операторы `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`.